# Use sed to add character in n'th position of matching string

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need to add a character in the n'th position (in this case 2nd) of a matching string.
For example, in a file `text.txt` I would like to add an N before the string and after the `"` only in the strings that contain `blah`

text.txt:

```
"1blah8","na","8blah4"  
"2blah5","na","10blah4"  
"5blah5","na","1blah234"
```

I want to get a text2.txt:

```
"Ν1blah8","na","Ν8blah4"  
"Ν2blah5","na","Ν10blah4"  
"Ν5blah5","na","Ν1blah234"
```

I have tried `sed 's/.*blah.*/N&/' text.txt > text2.txt`
but I get the `N` before the `"` and only in the first found string of each line.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach:

```
$ sed 's/"\([^"]*blah[^"]*"\)/"N\1/g' test.txt 
"N1blah8","na","N8blah4"  
"N2blah5","na","N10blah4"  
"N5blah5","na","1blah234
```

The regex is looking for a `"`, then 0 or more non-`"` characters followed by a `blah`, and then then 0 or more non-`"` again. Because of the parentheses, this is *captured* and can later be referred to as `\1`. Therefore, the command will substitute the matched pattern with itself (`\1`) but with a `"N` appended. That's why the first `"` is outside the parentheses. The `/g` modifier at the end makes it subsstitute all matching string in each line.

If your `sed` version supports it, you can simplify it to:

```
sed -E 's/"([^"]*blah[^"]*")/"N\1/g'
```

Answer (score 5):

To get `sed` to repeat the substitution for all matches on a line, add the `g` flag after the last `/`:

```
$ sed 's/[^"]*blah/N&/g' test.txt
```

The `g` flag will cause the substitution to be made "for all non-overlapping matches of the regular expression, not just the first one" (quote from the manual on my system).

I've also changed the regular expression a tiny bit so that all the characters that are not `"` before `blah` are matched. This way the substitution will insert the `N` just before the first digit, just after the `"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to insert after the `n`th character (where `n` is an arbitrary value) then you should avoid `sed`. There are better tools for this job (like `awk` or `perl`, `python` etc) e.g. with `awk` you can use a variable `n` to insert `STRING` after the `n`th character in each field that matches `PATTERN`:

```
awk -vn=2 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){ if ($i ~ /PATTERN/){
h=substr($i,1,n);t=substr($i,n+1,length($i));$i=h "STRING" t}}};1' infile
```

This assumes your file is a simple *csv* file (no commas embedded in your fields).

Answer (score 1):

CSV parsing and processing may be real complex. Here is a perl oneliner which put the N in front of column one and three, independently of the content:

Step 1, strip the double quotes:

```
@F = map { /"(.*)"/ } @F;
```

Step 2, inserting the `N` on column one and three

```
$F[0,2] =~ s/^/N/;
```

Step 3, join the array as CSV

```
printf qq("%s"\n), join q(","), @F
```

run perl:

```
perl -F, -ane '@F = map { /"(.*)"/ } @F; $F[0,2] =~ s/^/N/; printf qq("%s"\n), join q(","), @F' csvfile
```

Edit: new approach to avoid the security risk of eval expression (thank you terdon).

Comment: OP doesn't want to do it "independently of the content"... and the actual data might be different (e.g. `blah` might be in the 5th column on the 10th row)

Comment: @don_crissti: Do you think, there is a constant "blah" in every record?

Comment: I do _not_ think there's a `blah` in every record I'm just trying to tell you that you're hardcoding values when there's no point doing that. Unless OP is extremely explicit always assume unknown input. IOW try to answer the Q as it is quite clear: it asks how to insert only when field matches a pattern it doesn't ask to insert in front of column one and two

Comment: @terdon: it works, see the testrun.